# Hide and Show one Record at Time

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I fetch all of the records and display each article one after the other. Basically off the start the last `section#rest_of_profile` is hidden but when the user selects the `a#view_full_profile` in the first section I want to only show the one section in the article not all of them in each article. I Haven't been able to find a solution yet. The closest I have gotten is showing them all but hiding the only one I want to show. I appreciate any help/advice you can give.

```
var allRecords = $('section#rest_of_profile').hide();
    $('a#view_full_profile').click(function(){
        allRecords.slideUp();
        $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
        return false;
    });

<article class="searched-record">
<section>
    <figure>
        <img src="http://digitalhumanlibrary.com/wp-content/themes/thematicChild/images/profile/anonymous-search-profile.png" alt="Member Profile Avatar">
    </figure>
    <nav class="member-social">
        <ul>
            <li><a href=""><span>&#102 </span></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href=""><span>&#108 </span></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href=""><span>&#116 </span></a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="member-skype" href=""></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</section>
<section>
    <div><span>meBook: </span></div>
    <div><span>Contact Name: </span></div>
    <div><strong><span>Country: </span></strong>
    </div>
    <div><strong><span>Province/State: </span>'.$state.'</strong>
    </div>
    <div><strong><span>City: </span></strong>
    </div>
    <div><strong><span>Time Zone: </span></strong>
    </div>
    <div><strong><span>Program Focus: </span></strong>
    </div>
    <div><strong><span>Occupation: </span></strong>
    </div>
    <div><strong><span>Areas of Expertise: </span></strong>
    </div>
    <div><strong><span>Target Audience: </span></strong>
    </div>
    <div><strong><span>Video Conferencing Platforms: </span></strong>
    </div>  
    <a id="view_full_profile" href="">View Full Profile</a>

</section>
<section id="rest_of_profile">
    <div><strong><span>Email: </span><a href=""></a></strong>
    </div>
    <div><strong><span>Phone: </span></strong>
    </div>
    <div><strong><span>Website: </span></strong>
    </div>
    <div><strong><span>Profile Description: </span></strong>
    </div>
    <div><strong><span>Profile Learning Goals : </span></strong>
    </div>
    <div><strong><span>Curriculum Links: </span></strong>
    </div>
    <div><strong><span>Maximium # of Students: </span></strong>
    </div>
    <div><strong><span>Minimum # of Students: </span></strong>
    </div>
    <div><strong><span>Program Format: </span></strong>
    </div>
    <div><strong><span>Program Length: </span></strong>
    </div>
    <div><strong><span>Program Cost: </span></strong>
    </div>
    <div><strong><span>Technology Specifications: </span></strong>
    </div>
    <div><strong><span>How to Register: </span></strong>
    </div>
    <div><strong><span>Record: </span></strong>
    </div>
    <div><strong><span>Cancellation Policy: </span></strong>
    </div>
    <div><strong><span>Who Can Contact Me: </span></strong>
    </div>
</section>
<footer></footer>
</article>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `var allRecords = $('section#rest_of_profile').hide();` be `var allRecords = $('section#rest_of_profile');` ?

Comment: I have tried that as well, but I need $('section$rest_of_profile').hide and then var allRecords = $('section#rest_of_profile'); an it still does exactly the opposite, hides the one I want to show and shows all the others.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle showing your problem?

Comment: Ok... so here the fiddle but it actually works like it is supposed to in the fiddle but not on the browser, I don't get it http://jsfiddle.net/sQN3B/1/

Comment: That confuses me even more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I had walk the DOM better. Go back target the parent first then select the child I wanted to hide and show. Would be interested to see a more efficient solution instead of repeating the same code for another hide button, but for the time being she Works beauty, here is the code.

```
/**********************************/
    /*SEARCH PROFILE FUNCTIONS*/
/**********************************/
    $('section#rest_of_profile').hide();
    $('a#hide_full_profile').hide();
    //View Full profile Only
    $('a#view_full_profile').on('click',function(){
        $(this).parent('article.searched-record').children('section#rest_of_profile').toggle('slow');
        $('a#view_full_profile').hide();
        $('a#hide_full_profile').show();
    });
    //Hide Full profile Only
    $('a#hide_full_profile').on('click',function(){
        $(this).parent('article.searched-record').children('section#rest_of_profile').toggle('slow');
        $('a#view_full_profile').show();
        $('a#hide_full_profile').hide();
    });
```